# Moving multiple images to another worksheet using VBA - new location

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am creating a new sheet with the goal of reorganizing the information on another sheet. I have been able to move all other information to the other sheet in the format needed, but I can not move images/pictures of the parts.

I have tried using the code shown below, but referencing the cell the images are in, but it does not copy. I did a little research and looked at if there was a simple way to move images just by copy-pasting cells through VBA and it does not seem to work. I also look at trying to rename all the shapes, but to no success.

```
'find the last row of values
Worksheets("Eyelets").Activate

LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 3

Worksheets("Plot").Activate

'1st column of values
For i = 2 To LastRow Step 4

Count = Count + 1

x = i + Count

'Store all variables in the row
RDPNHold = Worksheets("Eyelets").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0)
FDPNHold = Worksheets("Eyelets").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 1)
WRHold = Worksheets("Eyelets").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 4)
MatHold = Worksheets("Eyelets").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 9)
DiamHold = Worksheets("Eyelets").Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 5).Value



'Move All Part Numbers to next sheet.
Worksheets("Plot").Range("A1").Offset(x - 2, 0) = RDPNText & RDPNHold
Worksheets("Plot").Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 0) = FDPNText & FDPNHold
Worksheets("Plot").Range("A1").Offset(x, 0) = WRText & WRHold
Worksheets("Plot").Range("A1").Offset(x + 1, 0) = MatText & MatHold & DiamText & DiamHold


'Bold Specific parts of the cells
Worksheets("Plot").Range("A1").Offset(x - 2, 0).Characters(Len(lngIDStart), 3).Font.Bold = True
Worksheets("Plot").Range("A1").Offset(x - 1, 0).Characters(Len(lngIDStart), 3).Font.Bold = True
Worksheets("Plot").Range("A1").Offset(x, 0).Characters(Len(lngIDStart), 3).Font.Bold = True
Worksheets("Plot").Range("A1").Offset(x + 1, 0).Characters(Len(lngIDStart), 4).Font.Bold = True
Worksheets("Plot").Range("A1").Offset(x + 1, 0).Characters(Len(lngIDStart) + 13, 5).Font.Bold = True

Next i
```

[Information not formateed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gE1Lr.png) This image shows how the information is already organized (I changed values due to work-related information)

[Formatted Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukURh.png) This image shows how I am trying to format the information, and as shown the blank space for the images.

Any ideas or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a starting point:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim shtSource As Worksheet, shtDest As Worksheet
    '....

    Set shtSource = Worksheets("Eyelets")
    Set shtDest = Worksheets("Plots")

    '....

    If CopyPicFromCell(shtSource.Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 2)) Then
        'copied the picture, so paste to shtDest
        shtDest.Paste
        With shtDest.Shapes(shtDest.Shapes.Count)
            .Top = shtDest.Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Top
            .Left = shtDest.Range("A1").Offset(0, 1).Left
        End With
    End If


End Sub



'see if there's a shape to be copied from a given cell
'  return True if one was found
Function CopyPicFromCell(c As Range)
    Const MARGIN As Long = 10 '<< how far the picture can be out of place
    Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In c.Parent.Shapes
        'check the TopLeftCell and the shape's position
        If shp.TopLeftCell.Address = c.Address Or _
            (Abs(shp.Left - c.Left) < MARGIN And Abs(shp.Top - c.Top) < MARGIN) Then
            shp.Copy
            CopyPicFromCell = True
            Exit For '<< done checking
        End If
    Next shp
End Function
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! I changed a few references and added a few more lines so the images are centered, but this was exactly what I needed. Thank you!